# What type of paper and which size to use for flyers?

Tags: print-design, print-production, paper, paper-size

I am a doctor by profession and have recently set up my own clinic. For this I want to print out flyers in order to let the general public know about my newly opened clinic.

Don't have much knowledge in this, thus I need some help in selecting a **paper type** and the correct **size** for my flyers.

The flyers would be distributed by-hand, along with newspapers, for pickup, etc. 5000 copies probably.

Answer (score 3):

There are **no standard sizes or stocks**. A "flier" can be any size on any stock.

You can use whatever size and stock you want. The word "flier" on its own designates the intended usage, not the appearance in any way.

To relate this to your profession.... this question is similar to asking, "What ethnicity is a patient?" There is no "standard" answer.

Use whatever size you feel works best and whatever stock you feel conveys the message you wish to convey. For a medical practice you probably don't want to use oversized fluorescent green stock. It's that sort of aesthetic determination that would indicate a stock which works for you.

If you are uncertain about this, whoever is printing the flier may be able to assist with these choices. If you are doing this yourself, look for fliers you like and try to mimic the qualities you find appealing, or hire someone to determine this for you based upon your *specific* needs.

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to deliver by hand I would go with some sort of gloss or semi-gloss finish. It will hold up to dirty hands and the weather much better especially if you're going to be leaving them outside in the elements at all.

Size and all of that is up to you. Talk to a print shop and get some samples and feedback from them.

Answer (score 0):

[DL](http://dlsize.com.au/) is a popular flyer format, that's 99×210mm or ⅓ of a landscape A4.

Contact a local printer and ask them what is their standard paper for DL flyers. They will probably give you a couple of options to choose from.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

A4 is the most used paper size for Flyers. The dimensions of an A4 page are 297mm high x 210mm wide (11.69 inches x 8.27 inches).

Comment: You can use A4 if you want, but I personally think it's too big and I've never seen one that size, always smaller. Specially distributed by hand.